# Add delay in ValueAnimator with multiple values

Tags: android, objectanimator

I'm using ValueAnimator with multiple int values. The thing is that is there a way to add delay after completion of each range in it. i.e. lets says values are val_1 = 500, val_2 = 5000, val_3 = 3500, val_4 = 3800 , now when val_1 to val_2 cycle is completed then to start from val_2 -> val_3 i want to add a small delay.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(val_1, val_2, val_3, val_4);
anim.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
            int val = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
             circle.setRadius(val);

        });
```

Comment: Have you tried any handler and runnable??

Comment: yes, handler didn't work as well. In animation listener onEnd function will call at completion of all values. and if use onUpdateListener with a condition like if(animatedvalue== val_3) . That doesn't work because it is not necessary that animator will touch that value.